# Order by value in serialized string

Tags: mysql

I'm having a database that holds a serialized string like this:

```
[gundealer|0
mayor|0
umlf|0
sbgfboss|0
ems|0
trader|0
thief|0
cp|0
umflboss|0
guard|0
sbgf|0
]
```

Is there a possible way to make a query to order by a subitem of this serialized string?

Comment: It is possible (and I have done it for a php serialized array stored within a MySQL field), but likely to perform badly.

Comment: Well grabbing 66k records in php and sorting it will be a hell to. That is why i'm asking. If it would be possible in the query it would save me alot of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Her you go with a demo way to do it:-

```
SELECT SerializeTest.*
FROM SerializeTest 
INNER JOIN (SELECT SerializeTest.Id, SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING( SomeField, 2, LENGTH( SomeField ) -2 ) , '|', anInt +1 ) , '|', -1 ) AS SortValue
FROM SerializeTest, 
(SELECT a.i+b.i*10 AS anInt FROM integers a, integers b) Sub1
WHERE MOD(anInt, 2) =1
AND anInt <=  (LENGTH(SomeField) - LENGTH(REPLACE(SomeField,'|', '' )))
AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(SomeField,2, LENGTH(SomeField) -2), '|', anInt), '|', -1) = 'ems') Sub2
ON SerializeTest.Id = Sub2.Id
ORDER BY SortValue
```

This relies on a table called integers with a single column called i and 10 rows with values from 0 to 9. This is joined against itself to get a range of integers (you can easily expand this part to get a larger range of numbers depending on the max number of values in the serialised array).

This integer is used to find the | values that delimit values, and from that extract the value that follows the key value. Note I have assumed that you have another pipe between each value. Ie, your data would be something like:-

```
INSERT INTO `SerializeTest` (`Id`, `SomeField`) VALUES
(1, '[gundealer|1|mayor|0|umlf|3|sbgfboss|0|ems|5|trader|0|thief|0|cp|0|umflboss|0|guard|0|sbgf|0]'),
(2, '[gundealer|1|mayor|0|umlf|3|sbgfboss|0|ems|9|trader|0|thief|0|cp|0|umflboss|0|guard|0|sbgf|0]'),
(3, '[gundealer|1|mayor|0|umlf|3|sbgfboss|0|ems|8|trader|0|thief|0|cp|0|umflboss|0|guard|0|sbgf|0]');
```

Note that I really wouldn't recommend you use this in a live environment. Not only as I suspect the performance would degrade rapidly but also because it is not exactly easy to understand

Comment: Yea you are right, if i read it correctly i can't apply it to my situation. the field doesn't contain these set values. It depents from  user to user. I'm better of parsing the order through PHP i guess.

Comment: You probably could still use it. The subselect that is used to get the sort value can be repeated to sort on multiple fields, and you can use a LEFT OUTER JOIN to cope with the situations where a row doesn't have one of the values you want to sort on. However it would generally be better to split these values off onto a separate table.